# EWS Item loses loaded property while executing code

Tags: c#, .net, exchangewebservices

Im trying to load and use the properties of EWS Items. During my codes execution the object loses it's value. 
Im loading messageId, attachments and subjuect.

Here's my code:

'''

```
            FindItemsResults<Item> items = EwsHelper.GetMails(credentials);  //Gets the items from the exchange service object. This method populate FindItemResults. It works.

            //Find correct EmailMessage with messageId (mailInput.MessageId is a param to my code to verify that I found the correct mail.
            string messageId = mailInput.MessageId;                             
            //The Id.UniqueId can be found. The property is loaded inside of the "EwsHelper.GetMails".
            foreach (Item item in items.Where(i => i.Id.UniqueId == messageId))
            {
                //Here im loading all the properties I need once again. I can verify that the object does have loaded property through the debugger. Everything is fine!
                item.Load(new PropertySet(ItemSchema.Subject,
                    ItemSchema.Id, ItemSchema.Attachments));
                if (item == null || !(item is EmailMessage))
                    throw new Exception();

                dynamic fileObj = new ExpandoObject();                  
                //Here the item.Subject (which recently was loaded) is null... Cant figure out why?!
                fileObj.Filename = $"{item.Subject.RemoveInvalidFileNameChar()}.msg";
            }
```

'''

Comment: Error message: You must load or assign this property before you can read its value.

Comment: I can get it to work if I reload the properties just before Im using them. But I do not want to call EWS all the time through out my code...